# Convert DOS line endings to Linux line endings and vice versa in java

Tags: java, unix, line-endings

Any suggestions on how to effectivley do this? I need it for autmization of .sql-data-delivery and couldn't find a solution till now. For reading out the encoding i use the juniversalchardet-1.0.3 library, which works pretty well. Still i also have to read out the the line-ending format and if needed change it. any help would be apprececiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: http://ostermiller.org/utils/LineEnds.html
Works like a charm. Feel free to use it if u have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)-class. 
They have the fields [LINE_SEPARATOR_UNIX](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#LINE_SEPARATOR_UNIX) and [LINE_SEPARATOR_WINDOWS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#LINE_SEPARATOR_WINDOWS).